# Can I pass a skill check even if my skill level is below the requirement?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Is possible in Fallout New Vegas to pass a skill check if your skill level is below the level required? I have tried several times but I always fail.

For example if I'm talking to an NPC and I want to convince him, let's say I need Barter 30 but my skill level is 20, could I pass this skill check without using a magazine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From doing some reading [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/6leg7f/fallout_new_vegas_on_skills_and_skill_checks/) and actually playing through New Vegas currently, it would seem that no, these skill checks are absolute. Much the same way that you cannot pick certain locks without 60 Lockpick skill, the same applies to speech checks for things like Barter and Speech.

Comment: You are correct it was actually one of the things oblivion changed compared to fallout 3. I recall reading something Josh Sawyer wrote about that. Sadly I don't have a source for that. But I know for certain it was chainged compared to fallout 3. It is no longer a dice roll.

Answer (score 1):

I have played an insane amount of NV and can confirm that there is no cheating around these, your options are raising your skills (I always max speech and lockpicking first in NV and FO3) and always grabbing every magasine you can (they have no weight so don't worry about taking too many), you can even get free ones in the Vegas with the mailbox like machines by the NCR building, (not the large embassy but the train station opposite from the topps.

I would recommend saving often on console, if you play PC just make a quicksave everynow and then (should be bound to F5) and if there is a check that you really want to do than revert your save. It's just one of the few annoying things about first time playthroughs.